# LWJGL Projection Matrix - Nothing Happens

Tags: java, lwjgl, vbo, opengl-3, projection-matrix

Currently, I'm attempting to create a Camera class in LWJGL, but I've been running into a problem with the projection matrix. For some reason, when I try to multiply the vertices by the projection matrix, nothing at all appears on screen.

**Camera class**

```
public class Camera {

private Vector3f position, rotation;
private Matrix4f view;

private final Vector3f xAxis, yAxis, zAxis;

private float fov, aspect, zNear, zFar;
private Matrix4f projection;

public Camera(float fov, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar){
    this.fov = fov;
    this.aspect = aspect;
    this.zNear = zNear;
    this.zFar = zFar;

    projection = createPerspectiveProjection(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);

    position = new Vector3f();
    rotation = new Vector3f();
    view = new Matrix4f();
    view.setIdentity();

    xAxis = new Vector3f(1, 0, 0);
    yAxis = new Vector3f(0, 1, 0);
    zAxis = new Vector3f(0, 0, 1);
}

public void addRotation(float x, float y, float z){
    rotation.x += x;
    rotation.y += y;
    rotation.z += z;

    apply();
}

public void move(float x, float y, float z){
    position.x += x;
    position.y += y;
    position.z += z;

    apply();
}

public Matrix4f getView(){
    return view;
}

public Matrix4f getProjection(){
    return projection;
}

private void apply(){
    view.setIdentity();

    view.rotate(rotation.x, xAxis);
    view.rotate(rotation.y, yAxis);
    view.rotate(rotation.z, zAxis);

    view.translate(position);
}

private Matrix4f createPerspectiveProjection(float fov, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar){
    Matrix4f mat = new Matrix4f();

    float yScale = (float) (1 / (Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov / 2))));
    float xScale = yScale / aspect;
    float frustrumLength = zFar - zNear;

    mat.m00 = xScale;
    mat.m11 = yScale;
    mat.m22 = -((zFar + zNear) / frustrumLength);
    mat.m23 = -1;
    mat.m32  = -((2 * zFar * zNear) / frustrumLength);
    mat.m33 = 0;

    return mat;
}

}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Game implements Runnable {

public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final int HEIGHT = 600;

public static final DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

int vaoID;

ShaderProgram program;
Camera camera;

Model model;

public Game(){
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public void run(){
    init();

    while(true){
        if(Display.isCloseRequested())
            break;

        update(Timer.getElapsedTime());

        render();

        Display.sync(60);
        Display.update();
    }

    Display.destroy();
}

public void init(){
    try{
        Display.setTitle("Ludum Dare!");
        Display.setDisplayMode(dm);
        Display.create();
    }catch(LWJGLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Timer.start();

    camera = new Camera(60.0f, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    program = new ShaderProgram("res/shader/defaultshader.vert", "res/shader/defaultshader.frag");

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    model = new Model(new float[] {
        -1, -1, 1,
        1, -1, 1,
        0, 1, 1
    });
}

public void update(float delta){

}

public void render(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    program.bind();

    program.setUniform("model_matrix", model.getModel());
    program.setUniform("view_matrix", camera.getView());
    program.setUniform("projection_matrix", camera.getProjection());

    model.render();

    program.unbind();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Game();
}

}
```

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex_modelspace;

uniform mat4 model_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;

void main(){
    mat4 modelviewprojection_matrix = projection_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix;
    vec4 vertex = vec4(vertex_modelspace, 1.0);

    gl_Position = modelviewprojection_matrix * vertex;
}
```

**ShaderProgram class**

```
public class ShaderProgram {

private int vertexShaderID, fragmentShaderID;
private int programID;

public ShaderProgram(String vertPath, String fragPath){
    programID = glCreateProgram();

    vertexShaderID = attachShader(vertPath, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShaderID = attachShader(fragPath, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    link();
}

private int attachShader(String path, int type){
    StringBuilder shaderSource = new StringBuilder();

    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
        String line;

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        reader.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error reading from shader " + path);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println("Compiling shader " + path);
    int id = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(id, shaderSource);
    glCompileShader(id);

    if(glGetShaderi(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE){
        System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(id, 1000));
        System.exit(1);
    }

    return id;
}

private void link(){
    System.out.println("Linking program...");
    glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(programID);
}

public void bind(){
    glUseProgram(programID);
}

public void unbind(){
    glUseProgram(0);
}

public void setUniform(String name, Matrix4f value){
    FloatBuffer matrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    value.store(matrix); matrix.flip();
    glUniformMatrix4(glGetUniformLocation(programID, name), false, matrix);
}

}
```

When I run this, the VBO that I create (A triangle) doesn't appear, but when I leave the projection matrix out of the multiplication in the vertex shader, it runs just fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your zNear and zFar values look kinda strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that `model.getModel()` will return the identity matrix (just like your view matrix is identity). In that case, you have the following situation: You draw a triangle in the plane z=1.0. If you use identity as projection matrix also, you directly draw in clip space, and the trianlge will be on the far plane, so it is visible.

However, your `createPerspectiveProjection` function seems to be written with the standard OpenGL conventions in mind, so it is almost like what [`glFrustum()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml). (Your code is missing the parts which are labeled A and B in that manpage, so you are limited to a symmetric frustum, but that is fine in most cases.)
The conventions used for this matrix were that the camera is looking into the -z direction, and the `zNear` and `zFar` parameters are actually maped such that a point at `z_eye=-zNear` is projected to the near plane (`z_ndc=-1`), and a point at `z_eye=-zFar` is projected to the far plane (`z_ndc=1`). So your triangle at z=1 is just behind the camera, if you apply that projection matrix.

Comment: Can't believe that I didn't catch that! Thanks!