# lwjgl Model(not from Blender) rendering behind the camera from +Z to -Z

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, opengl-3, projection-matrix

I am trying to rendering a model but it is projecting behind the camera, i am thinking of the problem being in the projection matrix from the link having the same problem [LWJGL Projection Matrix - Nothing Happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187262/lwjgl-projection-matrix-nothing-happens). I modified the projection matrix but still nothing happens, this is my projection matrix

```
private static final float FOV = 70;
private static final float NEAR_PLANE = 0.1f;
private static final float FAR_PLANE = 10000;
private void createProjectionMatrix() {
        float aspectRatio = (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight();
        float y_scale = (float) ((1f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV / 2f))) * aspectRatio);
        float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
        float frustum_length = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE;

        float bottom = -NEAR_PLANE * (float) Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV) / 2f);
        float top = -bottom;
        float left = aspectRatio * bottom;
        float right = -left;

        projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m20 = (right+left) / (right-left); //
        projectionMatrix.m21 = (top+bottom) / (top-bottom); //
        projectionMatrix.m22 = -((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
        projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * NEAR_PLANE * FAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;
    }
```

Edit:Main Loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        DisplayManager.createDisplay();
        Loader loader = new Loader();
        StaticShader shader = new StaticShader();
        Renderer renderer = new Renderer(shader);

        float[] vertices = {
                1409.598f, -58.85f, 1471.946f,
                1460.572f, -58.9047f, 1462.047f,
                1408.506f, -20.5531f, 1471.137f
        };

        int[] indices = {
            0, 1, 2
        };

        float[] textures = {0, 0};

        RawModel model = loader.loadToVAO(vertices,textures, indices);

        TexturedModel staticModel = new TexturedModel(model,new ModelTexture(loader.loadTexture("image")));

        Entity entity = new Entity(staticModel, new Vector3f(0,0,5),0,0,0,1);

        Camera camera = new Camera(entity);

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            camera.move();
            renderer.prepare();
            shader.start();
            shader.loadViewMatrix(camera);
            renderer.render(entity,shader);
            shader.stop();
            DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
        }

        shader.cleanUp();
        loader.cleanUp();
        DisplayManager.closeDisplay();
    }
```

Renderer class:

```
public class Renderer {

    private static final float FOV = 70;
    private static final float NEAR_PLANE = 0.1f;
    private static final float FAR_PLANE = 5000;

    private Matrix4f projectionMatrix;

    public Renderer(StaticShader shader) {
        createProjectionMatrix();
        shader.start();
        shader.loadProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
        shader.stop();
    }

    public void prepare() {
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glClearColor(0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);
    }

    public void render(Entity entity, StaticShader shader) {
        TexturedModel model = entity.getModel();
        RawModel rawModel = model.getRawModel();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(rawModel.getVaoID());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        Matrix4f transformationMatrix = Maths.createTransformationMatrix(entity.getPosition(),
                entity.getRotX(), entity.getRotY(), entity.getRotZ(), entity.getScale());
        shader.loadTransformationMatrix(transformationMatrix);
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, model.getTexture().getID());
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, rawModel.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    private void createProjectionMatrix(){
        float aspectRatio = (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight();
        float y_scale = (float) ((1f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV / 2f))) * aspectRatio);
        float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
        float frustum_length = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE;

        projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;
        projectionMatrix.m22 = -((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
        projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * NEAR_PLANE * FAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
        projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;
    }
}
```

VertexShader:

```
#version 150

in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

void main(void){

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

Maths Class:

```
public static Matrix4f createTransformationMatrix(Vector3f translation, float rx, float ry,
            float rz, float scale) {
        Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
        matrix.setIdentity();
        Matrix4f.translate(translation, matrix, matrix);
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rx), new Vector3f(1,0,0), matrix, matrix);
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(ry), new Vector3f(0,1,0), matrix, matrix);
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rz), new Vector3f(0,0,1), matrix, matrix);
        Matrix4f.scale(new Vector3f(scale,scale,scale), matrix, matrix);
        return matrix;
    }

    public static Matrix4f createViewMatrix(Camera camera) {
        Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
        viewMatrix.setIdentity();
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getPitch()), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), viewMatrix,
                viewMatrix);
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getYaw()), new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
        Vector3f cameraPos = camera.getPosition();
        Vector3f negativeCameraPos = new Vector3f(-cameraPos.x,-cameraPos.y,-cameraPos.z);
        Matrix4f.translate(negativeCameraPos, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
        return viewMatrix;
    }
```

Can find the full code am running in this link [Complete code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ps9uu2clslke3qd/AADzqmNvCjslMipVvCMusuLCa?dl=0)

Comment: *"but it is projecting behind the camera"* - How do you know that it is projecting "behind the camera"? What is the view matrix. Note, in view space in a right handed coordinate system, the z axis points out of the viewport, this means positive view space z coordinates are behind the camera and increasing negative coordinates are in the depth of the frustum. Is that your issue?

Comment: I have added camera movement from a tutorial the triangle rotates in circular motion that is when i know its projecting but not inside camera view.My vertices are in multiples of 1000 rabbid, is that an issue ? I have edited my code and can find the complete code am running in dropbox.I am struggling with this around a week, Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @Rabbid76 any idea of what might went wrong ?